# Why is (floated) list item going to next line

Tags: css

I have

```
<footer class="meta">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="numNotes">3 notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="numComments">10 comments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="datePosted">3rd Feb 2011</a></li>
    <li class="tags">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tag name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tag name</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

I am wondering why my last tag item goes to the next line

[image]

http://jiewmeng.kodingen.com/demos/folio-wip/index.html

Comment: simply too much content for footer, hence it wraps to the next line. What is your expected behavior? One line? Make footer wider.

Comment: @moontear, I expected the footer to stretch, after all, I havent set a fixed width & the parent still have space to stretch http://imgur.com/M1yVJ.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to enforce a one-line display, by adding:

```
li.tags,
li.tags > ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As others have pointed out, however, it drops to the next line due to width of the content being greater than the width of the parent element.

Having played around with this, it turns out that, for `white-space: no-wrap;` to work, you'd also need to use `display: inline;` (or `display: inline-block;`) on the `li` elements.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KeKbr/).

Answer (score 0):

The second tag name doesn't have space to float so it drops to the next line.

If you give the parent li more width it will stay on the same line

Answer (score 0):

It's just overflowing since there's too much content to fit in the parent box. You can very easily check these things if you install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in your Firefox browser.

Comment: I have Firebug and thats what i use to add content as u can see from http://imgur.com/Ow3zA.jpg, it can stretch alot more, but the last element still drops down